Response.redirect not changing URL in the addressbar
I login with next-auth's Credential provide "SignIn". It routes to me to the /portal page after sign in but it keeps the url in address bar same /login. below is a code snippet from my auth.config.ts file
authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl, url } }) {
      try {
        const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
        const isRootOrDashboard =
          nextUrl.pathname === "/" || nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/portal");

        if (isRootOrDashboard) {
          if (!isLoggedIn) {
            return false;
          } else if (nextUrl.pathname === "/") {
            return Response.redirect(new URL("/portal", nextUrl));
          }
        } else if (isLoggedIn) {
          return Response.redirect(new URL("/portal", nextUrl));
        }
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
    },

